# Kashmir Shaivism on 10 major Upanishads

Tags: upanishads, kashmiri-shaivism, commentary, abhinavagupta

Bhagavadpad Adi Shankaracharya commentary on Upanishads is no doubt a masterpiece, but it is very detailed, sometimes so much detailed that a beginner like me feel completely lost in a completely different subject matter than what is being discussed in the Upanishad.

Same happened to me when I was reading Bhagavadpad Adi Shankaracharya commentary on Bhagvad Gita but then I came across Abhinavgupta Acharya's commentary on Bhagavad Gita and loved it very much because of its conciseness and hitting the main point accurately.

In his own words

> किमन्यैस्तत्वदर्शनविघ्नमात्रफलैर्वाग्जालैः।
> (What’s the use of web-of-words which only prove obstacle in path of highest realization?)

This makes me wonder are there some other "well-known" commentaries on the Upanishads from Kashmir Shaivism Acharyas like Abhinavgupta?

Comment: Asking for "good-commentaries", might turn to an opinion. Asking for "other - well known commentaries" makes it more generic

Comment: @Vivikta Yes, that works too. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

No there is no commentary on Upanishads by Kashmiri Shaiva Acharya Shree Abhinavagupta. His main focus was to compile all Tantra texts which he did by writing text Tantraloka. Here are the list of his works:

1. Paratrishika-vivarana/vivritti
2. Malinivijaya-varttika
3. Tantraloka
4. Tantrasara
5. Tantravatadhanika
6. Dhvanyalokalochana
7. Abhinavabharati
8. Bhagavad-gitartha-samgraha
9. Paramartha-sara
10. Isvara-pratyabhijna-vimarshini (Laghvi-vimarshini)
11. Isvarapratyabhijna-vivritti-vimarshini
12. Krama-stotra
13. Dehastadevatachakra-stotra
14. Bhairava-stotra
15. Paramarthedvadashika
16. Anubhavanivedanam
17. Paramartha-charcha
18. Mahopadeshavimshay-tika
19. Anuttara-tika
20. Tantrocchaya
21. Ghatakarparkulaka-vivritti
22. Kramakeli
23. Shivadrshtyalochana
24. Purvapanchika
25. Padarthapravesha-nirnaya-tika
26. Prakirnaka-vivarana
27. Prakarana-vivarana
28. Kavyakautuka-vivarana
29. Kathamukhatika
30. Laghviprakriya
31. Bhedavada-vidarana
32. Devistotra-vivarana
33. Tattvadhva-prakasika
34. Shiva-shaktyavinabhava-stotra
35. Bimba-pratibimbavada
36. Paramartha-samgraha
37. Anuttara-shataka
38. Prakarana-stotra
39. Natya-lochana
40. Anuttaratattva-vimarshini
41. Bodhapanchashika

Reference: [Abhinavagupta](https://www.sahapedia.org/abhinavagupta)

Only Upanishad which one of the Acharya from this lineage wrote is [Kaula-Upanishad](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kaula-upanishad-with-sanskrit-commentary-of-bhaskar-rai-NZF090/), A work of Bhaskara.

Comment: Op asks "like Abhinavgupta" - that means other acharyas from the Kashmiri sect are also included not just Abhinavgupta. :)

Comment: @Vivikta No Kashmiri Acharya was interested in Upanishad

Comment: Because they were into Tantra philosophy which itself is very eye opening and detailed.

Comment: Oh okay!..... So basically the only non tantric text Abhinavgupta Gupta gave bhashya on, was the Srimada Bhagvada Geeta?

Comment: Yes as you can see in the list. The Tantra texts are vast. Tantraloka itself is in 5-6 volumes. Because of which Abhinavagupta wrote its karika by name Tantrasaar.